# PhpStorm Docker PHPUnit Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, phpunit, phpstorm

- I [setup](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/11/docker-remote-interpreters/) PhpStorm: PHP, PHPUnit with Docker
- I see schema in PhpStorm/Database viewer
- I can use database in my application: register etc.
- I can run phpunit in PhpStorm
- But if I would like use database in tests, then I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
>   (SQL: select * from `tablename`)

The test working in container but broken in IDE. 
Do you have any ideas what is the problem in PhpStorm?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I m also looking for a solution

Comment: i finally resolved this problem. A nbsp character was in the hostname....

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this exact issue. Assuming you already have the Docker container and PHP interpreter set up, this is how I got it to connect to the MySQL container:

1. Run `docker network ls` from the CLI and saw the "lighthouse_default" network
2. Went to PHP > Test Frameworks and edited (clicked the folder) on my Docker container
3. Set Network mode to "lighthouse_default"
4. Added the lighthouse_mysql_1 image to the Links section

Obviously, in your situation the network name will likely be different. The real point is that I had to make sure I was using the right network *and* make sure the database image is in the Container Links.

Comment: That solved it for me as well for laradock (steps 1-3, skipped step 4). The network name is "laradock_backend"

Answer (score 6):

Do you use docker-compose (and is your db running in a different container)?

[Check if your CLI Interpreter is running with docker-compose settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK4yV.png)

Comment: Yes, I use docker-compose and a DB in different container.

Comment: make sure that your mysql container is running. It seems Phpstorm does not start the mysql container on its own

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem and found solution:

Go to:

```
Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks
```

Open:

```
Edit docker container settings (you need push on folder icon)
```

Inside opened window, you will find "links" section, add from list your database container and after saving all works perfect!

---

If you get error for different network configuration, update your docker-compose.yml with adding this sentence on each container:

```
network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: I think this won't work anymore with current docker version since "link" is now a legacy feature as far as I read. When I do it on PHPStorm I get "Loading container names..." "for ever" and I can not select anything. 
@Jason Adams' solution worked for me though.